# Auto/Automated login after Wake On Lan

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, automation, wake-on-lan

I have got the Wake On Lan feature working. But after I start the computers they get stuck at the windows login screen, obviously as the computers have passwords.

Is there any way to auto login after Wake On Lan or somehow automate the login process without removing the password. I found threads discussing a possibility that you could run a script as a service or something, but couldn't find a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this with Python and Windows Task Scheduler. With Task scheduler you can run tasks based on events like startup. I created a Python script that changes the password to a blank one and restarts the computer, this way it doesn't require the password for login. In Task Scheduler you have to check the **run with highest privileges** and **run whether the user is logged in or not**. Then I created another script that after log in event changes the password back to what it was.

In my opinion this is some kind of security flaw but more experienced people can give their opinion about that.

Answer (score 1):

## Method One:

Yes, you can disable **Require password** feature after screen goes off or Wake up from sleep:

1. Click **Settings -> Accounts**.
2. Click **Sign-in options** on the left side.
3. Select **Never** (off) under **Require sign in**.
4. When finished, you can close Settings to restart to check the result.

## Method Two:

1. Open the **advanced power settings** for your current chosen **power plan**.
2. Click on the Change settings that are currently unavailable link. (see screenshot below)
   [image]
3. Set the Require a password on wakeup settings to **No**.

Comment: I know that but I don't want to remove the password. I want to be able to auto login only after I start the computer with Wake On Lan, and I'm starting it from fully shutdown mode not from sleep.

Comment: If so, that's not possible. Since to help secure your PC, Windows requires users to sign in when it wakes from sleep or hibernate by default. We can only turn on or off to require sign-in on wakeup for all users in Windows 10. Automatically Sign in to User Account only for Startup.